# Trouble Parsing SOAP response in PHP using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using  cURL to POST a SOAP request. The response is as follows:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
  <wsa:Action>http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v3_1/TerminalLocationPort/getLocationForGroupResponse</wsa:Action>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
  <ns2:getLocationForGroupResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/terminal_location/v3_1/local">
     <ns2:result>
        <address>234983</address>
        <reportStatus>Retrieved</reportStatus>
        <currentLocation>
           <latitude>12.5665</latitude>
           <longitude>43.7708</longitude>
           <timestamp>2012-01-03T17:06:16.805+01:30</timestamp>
        </currentLocation>
     </ns2:result>
     <ns2:result>
        <address>423903</address>
        <reportStatus>Retrieved</reportStatus>
        <currentLocation>
           <latitude>12.2165</latitude>
           <longitude>43.6518</longitude>
           <timestamp>2012-01-03T17:06:16.824+01:30</timestamp>
        </currentLocation>
     </ns2:result>
  </ns2:getLocationForGroupResponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I use this to decode:

```
$err = curl_error($soap_do);
$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml->children($ns['env']);
$getaddressresponse = $soap->body->children($ns['ns2']);
foreach ($getaddressresponse->children() as $item) {
    echo (string) $item->address . '<br />';
}
```

I'm having trouble decoding this with SimpleXML. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928350/how-to-parse-soap-response) seems most relevant to my situation but I'm unable to apply it to my case as the simpleXML element just

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::children() [simplexmlelement.children]: Node no longer exists in C:\.php on line 33 /*(line with the for each statement)*/
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
If the server responds with the following error, how would I detect it..?

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Service Exception</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:ServiceException xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/common/v3_1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/terminal_location/v3_1/local">
               <messageId>SVC004</messageId>
               <text>Trip not Found for this MSISDN</text>
            </ns1:ServiceException>
         </detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable and property names are case sensitive and while I was testing it, it turned out there's other stuff as well. The following works:

```
$soap = $xml->children($ns['env']);
$getaddressresponse = $soap->Body->children($ns['ns2']);
foreach ($getaddressresponse->getLocationForGroupResponse->children($ns['ns2']) as $item)
{
    $item = $item->children();
    echo $item->address . '<br />';
}
```

To answer the updated question:

```
$fault = $soap->Body->children($ns['env']);
if (isset($fault->Fault))
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: would appreciate it if you could respond to the updated Question as well..Thanks

Comment: How would I reach the latitude/longitude properties?

Comment: Got it!
echo (string) $item->currentLocation->latitude

Comment: The same way you reach Body, Fault, etc. Get the children of it's parent node, e.g. `$currentLocation = $item->currentLocation->children(); echo $currentLocation->latitude;`

Comment: Wish I could give multiple ups! Thanks again.