# Parsing a SOAP response with PHP in different ways

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse SOAP response without SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928350/how-to-parse-soap-response-without-soapclient)

I have a simple nuSoap XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <LoginResult xmlns="http://Siddin.ServiceContracts/2006/09">FE99E5267950B241F96C96DC492ACAC542F67A55</LoginResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I'm trying to parse it with `simplexml_load_string` as suggested here: [parse an XML with SimpleXML which has multiple namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740730/parse-an-xml-with-simplexml-which-has-multiple-namespaces) and here: [Trouble Parsing SOAP response in PHP using simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712139/trouble-parsing-soap-response-in-php-using-simplexml), but I can't get it working.

This is my code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $this->getFullResponse() );
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');

foreach($xml->xpath('//soap:Body') as $header) {
    var_export($header->xpath('//LoginResult')); 
}
```

But I still get only this in result:

```
/* array ( )
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what simple thing am I missing to understand?

---

*The working end result with DOM by [MySqlError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611611/mysqlerror):*

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $response  );
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName( "LoginResult" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

*The working end result with SimpleXML by [ndm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1392379/ndm):*

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $response );
foreach($xml->xpath('//soap:Body') as $header) {
    echo (string)$header->LoginResult;
}
```

Comment: i would suggest PHP DOMDocument
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: do you want alternative solution using DOMDocument ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928350/how-to-parse-soap-response-without-soapclient

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $yourxmlresponse );

$LoginResults = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "LoginResult" );
$LoginResult = $LoginResults->item(0)->nodeValue;

var_export( $LoginResult );
```

Comment: I'm not getting any results out of this

Comment: if you change var_export to echo it will return without ' mark
var_export is just showing you that it's string

Comment: Thank you for the new approach for me ;)

Answer (score 5):

What's going wrong here is SimpleXMLs poor default namespace support. In order to fetch that node using an XPath expression, you'd need to register a prefix for the default namespace and use it in the query, even though the element isn't prefixed, for example:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//soap:Body') as $header) {
    $header->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://Siddin.ServiceContracts/2006/09');
    var_export($header->xpath('//default:LoginResult'));
}
```

However, actually there's no need to use XPath for accessing this node, you can simply access it directly:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//soap:Body') as $header) {
    var_export($header->LoginResult);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work in some way, but gives me string like this, witch is still not exactly what I need: `SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
   0 => 'FE99E5267950B241F96C96DC492ACAC542F67A55',
))`

Comment: Well, I've adapted your example code, ofcourse that's how a `var_export` of a SimpleXML node looks like, if you need to access the value, simply cast the node to a string: `(string)$header->LoginResult`

Comment: Thanx m8, too bad I can't accept two answers.

Comment: No problem, a vote is fine too ;)