# Parsing XML in PHP with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse the below XML , i have tryed loads of different solutions, i have provided an example of what i have tryed. I have read the SimpleXML documents and i still cant get this right. In the Example below all im trying to do is Echo out a line in the XML.

```
<?php
$xmlstr = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SubmitLeadResponse xmlns="https://test.com/">
<SubmitLeadResult>
<Result>C</Result>
<RedirectURL>https://testred.com</RedirectURL>
<ApplicantID>123</ApplicantID>
<ConfirmedPrice>0</ConfirmedPrice>
<PotentialPrice>0</PotentialPrice>
</SubmitLeadResult>
</SubmitLeadResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
;

?>


<?php

$SubmitLeadResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $SubmitLeadResponse->SubmitLeadResult[0]->RedirectURL;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code for SimpleXML

```
<?php
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SubmitLeadResponse xmlns="https://test.com/">
<SubmitLeadResult>
<Result>C</Result>
<RedirectURL>https://testred.com</RedirectURL>
<ApplicantID>123</ApplicantID>
<ConfirmedPrice>0</ConfirmedPrice>
<PotentialPrice>0</PotentialPrice>
</SubmitLeadResult>
</SubmitLeadResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
$get_xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($get_xml);
print"<pre>";
print_r((string)$xml->Body->SubmitLeadResponse->SubmitLeadResult->RedirectURL);
echo "<br /><br /><br />";
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: Hi @Chauhan , thank you. Could you add the your example , IF the RedirectURL contains a URL it gets Redirected to www.test.com and if it does not then echo "Failed"

Comment: $getRedirectUrl = (string)$xml->Body->SubmitLeadResponse->SubmitLeadResult->RedirectURL;
if($getRedirectUrl) {
  header("location:".$getRedirectUrl);
}
else {
 echo "Failed";
}
 
Add this line after $xml = simplexml_load_string($get_xml);

Comment: Thank you so much , if i can ask you one last question please i promise. How do i : IF Result = C then redirect using the redirect URL , IF Result is any other value echo Failed. Thank you so much :D

Comment: I am not getting you for  Result = C?

Comment: In the XML i get a <Result>C</Result> . If i get a <Result>C</Result> then they provide a URL , if i get any other result then they provide a failed url

Comment: $getResult = (string)$xml->Body->SubmitLeadResponse->SubmitLeadResult->Result;
$getRedirectUrl = (string)$xml->Body->SubmitLeadResponse->SubmitLeadResult->RedirectURL;
if($getResult=='C') {
  header("location:".$getRedirectUrl);
}
else {
 echo "Failed";
}

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit. Here's a working sample to get the RedirectURL:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SubmitLeadResponse xmlns="https://test.com/">
<SubmitLeadResult>
<Result>C</Result>
<RedirectURL>https://testred.com</RedirectURL>
<ApplicantID>123</ApplicantID>
<ConfirmedPrice>0</ConfirmedPrice>
<PotentialPrice>0</PotentialPrice>
</SubmitLeadResult>
</SubmitLeadResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $xmlstr );

$RedirectURL = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "RedirectURL" );
$RedirectURL = $LoginResults->item(0)->nodeValue;

var_dump( $RedirectURL );
```

Sample provided from this source: [There are also more informations to reading SOAP-envelopes without a soapclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969735/parsing-a-soap-response-with-php-in-different-ways)

Please note that it's good practice to omit the php closing tag and stay in the php-context as long as possible to avoid unexpected outputs (linebreaks).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML contains namespaced elements, so it's a little more complicated to parse. It can be done by passing the namespace values to `children()` like so:

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/oP5PXfAE)

```
$SubmitLeadResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo (string)$SubmitLeadResponse
          ->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
          ->Body
          ->children('https://test.com/')
          ->SubmitLeadResponse
          ->SubmitLeadResult
          ->RedirectURL;
```

Outputs

```
https://testred.com
```

Note: SimpleXML doesn't like new lines before the XML string, so remove the new line, making it:

```
$xmlstr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```