# Getting SOAP data into php array

Tags: php, sql, xml, soap

I am very new to SOAP and struggling with this!

I am calling for a SOAP response from an sql database

```
$client = new SoapClient("url......");
$soapquery = array('CoCode' => $cocode, 'WAPassword' => $webpass, 'strSQL' => $sqlt);
$soapresult = $client->SQL($soapquery);
$balance = $soapresult->SQLResult;
print_r($balance);
```

The result shows in Chrome as the value requested, but when inspecting the source it shows as an xml

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <TOTAL>3348.1200</TOTAL>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

How can i get this information into either a PHP string or if i am calling more than one field into an array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why soapClient isn't parsing your response, but for a quick fix, you can use the php function [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

Here is an example: [How to parse SOAP response without SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928350/how-to-parse-soap-response-without-soapclient)