# PHP SimpleXML objects with ":"

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is first time I tried to use SimpleXML... normally I was parsing xml files with regexp, but time to learn something new...

I got XML that contains:

```
            <resData>
                    <something:infData xmlns:something="<censored>" xsi:schemaLocation="<censored>">
                            <something:name>hello this is my name</something:name>
                            <something:key>
                                    <something:token>fdba8ee15e4473e12ac342ae15acef2</something:token>
                            </something:key>
                    </something:infData>
            </resData>
```

I am parseing xml via `simplexml_load_string()` function...

I can get resData as SimpleXMLObject via $xml->resData ... but how do I get `something:name` and `something:key -> something:token` ? I cannot use `$xml->resData->something:name` as it throws an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse SOAP response without SoapClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928350/how-to-parse-soap-response-without-soapclient)

Comment: And this might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12969863/1488915

Comment: I don't really understand this... so the only way is xpath?

Comment: I don't see answer to my question there... as getting list of objects is not what I need... still don't know how to get value from that thread. Could you please simply help me to get from given structure values of those two elements?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is:

`$xml->response->resData->children('something',true)->children('something',true)->name`

`$xml->response->resData->children('something',true)->children('something',true)->key->children('something',true)->token`